# Lambda expression weirdness in a LINQ to SQL 'where' condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I am working on an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) application which uses the repository pattern with [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL_.28formerly_called_DLINQ.29) as my data source. In my repository I expose the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
    return _context.GetTable<T>().Where(where);
}
```

I am able to call this by saying:

```
repository<User>().Find(u => true);
```

But if I try doing (when search is null)

```
repository<User>().Find(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? u.UserName.Contains(search) : true);
```

I get the error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: text

I thought the lambda expression would execute the same thing since the value of search is null, but this is clearly not the case.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show a bit more context? Lazy evaluation makes LINQ a litte tricky to analyse without seeing how you use its output.

Comment: both IsNullOrEmpty's and Contains's parameters are called `value` so the error does not come from them.

Comment: @SWeko: `string.Contains` wouldn't be throwing the exception, the expression parser's evaluation of the call to `string.Contains` to construct a `LIKE` expression would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the other answers, if you *have* to follow this ideal, you could simply do this instead:

```
repository<User>.Find(u => string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) || 
                           u.UserName.Contains(search));
```

**Before blindly implementing this, if you were to do so, please read Adam's answer to learn of consequences.**

Comment: I've just discovered if i say:

repository<User>.Find(u => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) || u.UserName.Contains(search)) && (!enabled.HasValue || u.Enabled == enabled.Value));

I get the same issue as before. Grr

Answer (score 3):

Because this is an expression, normal conditional operator logic (not evaluating the false expression) don't automatically apply. Since the expression is actually being translated into a SQL query expression, LINQ to SQL is evaluating the parameters of the condition, and in this case it's `null`. While `LIKE null` is valid SQL syntax, evidently LINQ to SQL doesn't appreciate being passed null. You'll have to construct two different queries, one for a null term, one for a non-null term.

Either that, or pass something like `string.Empty` to `Contains`. The only impact here will be the inability to use an index on the column, since the server will be doing a repeated conditional evaluation on every row, forcing a table scan. I'd advise using two queries without the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Contains expects a string. You should pass `string.Emtpy`.

```
u.UserName.Contains(search)
```

If you try this, it'll compile but you'll get a runtime error:

```
string str = "Leniel";

if (str.Contains(null))
{
    var num = 1;
}
```

Error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
```

Comment: `string.Contains` is not being invoked. The call to `string.Contains` in the expression is being translated to a `LIKE` expression in SQL. This translation is what's throwing the exception. Note the difference in names on the parameters (`value` vs. `text`)